# How to get the respective funtion to be triggered when the respective element is clicked when one element is a parent?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I click the icon the `clickIcon()` funtion should trigger and when I click the button the `clickBtn()` fuction should trigger. What is happening now is the **icon** click is being triggered as I want but when on **button** click both fuction is triggered.

What I want is only the respective function should trigger on click. How to get the respective funtion to be triggered when the respective element is clicked?

```js
clickBtn = () => {
  console.log("btn click")
}

clickIcon = () => {
  console.log("img click")
}
```

```css
.icon {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.icon>.buttons {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.7);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.icon:hover>.buttons {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon" (click)="clickIcon()">
  <div id="folderView">
    <i class="fa fa-folder" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 3em; color: #ddc808;"></i>
    <p>Folder</p>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button (click)="clickBtn()">Action 1</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you added the click event on div which have a class name "icon", so where ever you click on that div respective click event will call, as your button also lies in that div, so it calls both click event, try removing click event of 1st div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass the `event` to your button click handler, you can invoke [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) on it to prevent it from bubbling up to the containing element.

```js
clickBtn = (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation(); // prevent event from bubbling up to container
  console.log("btn click")
}

clickIcon = () => {
  console.log("img click")
}
```

```css
.icon {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.icon>.buttons {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.7);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.icon:hover>.buttons {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon" onclick="clickIcon(event)">
  <div id="folderView">
    <i class="fa fa-folder" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 3em; color: #ddc808;"></i>
    <p>Folder</p>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button onclick="clickBtn(event)">Action 1</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `event.stopPropagation()` in your `clickIcon()`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that's true because button and icon are child and parent respectively. If a child is triggered the parent functions also triggers, but you can prevent parents functions to trigger by using event.stopPropagation()

For Button:

```
<button (click)="clickBtn(event)">Action 1</button>
```

For Event Trigger

```
clickBtn = (e) => {
  console.log("btn click");
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Events propagate to the parent elements until they reach the html element. This is called event bubbling.

In your case, the event on button click is getting propagated to its parent and the parent click event is also getting triggered, this is default event behavior. If you don't want this to happen, you can call event.stopPropagation() on the innermost element which will stop the bubbling.

```js
clickBtn = (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log("btn click")
}

clickIcon = () => {
  console.log("img click")
}
```

```css
.icon {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.icon>.buttons {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.7);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.icon:hover>.buttons {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon" (click)="clickIcon()">
  <div id="folderView">
    <i class="fa fa-folder" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 3em; color: #ddc808;"></i>
    <p>Folder</p>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button (click)="clickBtn()">Action 1</button>
  </div>
</div>
```